# Passing data to Child Component ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, use-effect

## Background

I am working on a website where I have parent components and child components. The snippet below is a Google Map wrapper and a map component.

## Code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

// reactstrap components
import { Card, Container, Row } from "reactstrap";

// core components
import Header from "components/Headers/Header.js";
import LocationSearchInput from "../../components/Places";
import { useAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import * as queries from "../../graphql/queries";
import { API, graphqlOperation } from "aws-amplify";
import { geocodeByAddress, getLatLng } from "react-places-autocomplete";
import * as _ from "lodash";
import { collapseTextChangeRangesAcrossMultipleVersions } from "typescript";

const ChildComponent = (data, loc) => {
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  console.log("child props", data, loc);

  console.log("foo child", loc);
  // THIS WONT WORK BECAUSE WHEN IT FIRST LOADS ITS EMPTY
  // geocodeByAddress(loc[0].HomeLocation)
  //     .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
  //     .then(latLng => console.log('Success', latLng))
  //     .catch(error => console.error('Error', error))

  useEffect(() => {
console.log("child mount");
    let google = window.google;
    let map = mapRef.current;
    let lat = "40.748817";
    let lng = "-73.985428";
    const myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    const mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: myLatlng,
      scrollwheel: false,
      zoomControl: true,
      styles: [
        {
          featureType: "administrative",
          elementType: "labels.text.fill",
          stylers: [{ color: "#444444" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "landscape",
          elementType: "all",
          stylers: [{ color: "#f2f2f2" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "poi",
          elementType: "all",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "road",
          elementType: "all",
          stylers: [{ saturation: -100 }, { lightness: 45 }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "road.highway",
          elementType: "all",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "simplified" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "road.arterial",
          elementType: "labels.icon",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "transit",
          elementType: "all",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "water",
          elementType: "all",
          stylers: [{ color: "#5e72e4" }, { visibility: "on" }],
        },
      ],
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(map, mapOptions);

    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      title: "Light Bootstrap Dashboard PRO React!",
    });

    const contentString =
      '<div class="info-window-content"><h2>Light Bootstrap Dashboard PRO React</h2>' +
      "<p>A premium Admin for React-Bootstrap, Bootstrap, React, and React Hooks.</p></div>";

    const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log("child render");
  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{ height: `600px` }}
        className="map-canvas"
        id="map-canvas"
        ref={mapRef}
      ></div>
    </>
  );
};



//PARENT COMPONENT
const Parent = () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState([]);

  const { user, signOut } = useAuthenticator((context) => [context.user]);
  // console.log("user map", user);

  const [pin, setPin] = useState([]);

  const fetchFoo = async () => {
    console.log(user.attributes.email);
    try {
      const todoData = API.graphql(
        graphqlOperation(queries.listEmployees, {
          filter: {
            Email: {
              eq: user.attributes.email,
            },
          },
        })
      ).then((response) => {
          console.log("fetch resp", response);
          setFoo(response.data.listEmployees.items);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error facing Todos:", err);
    }
  };
  console.log("parent render");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("parent mount")
    fetchFoo();
  }, []);

  var json = [{a: "a", b:"b"}]

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {/* Page content */}
      {/* {foo} */}
      <Container className="mt--7" fluid>
        <Row>
          <div className="col">
            {/* <LocationSearchInput /> */}
          </div>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <div className="col">
            <Card className="shadow border-0">
              {/* <> */}
              <ChildComponent data={json} loc={{foo}}/>
              {/* </> */}
            </Card>
          </div>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

## Output

[image: console output #1]
[image: console output #2]

## Problem

The child component when it first reads the data it is empty but it is populated the second time it is loaded. I have tried to tweak the useEffect to work but the only difference I get is it'll perform an infinite loop if I remove the empty array.

Comment: Can you simplify the code you provided and add more clarity? Namely, what is an example parent component, child component, and relevant `useEffect` action?

Comment: I would fix first declaration of MapWrapper... replace "const MapWrapper = (data, loc)" to "const MapWrapper = ({data, loc}). You always have first argument (data in your case) to be "props" that contains "data" and "loc". Which means that what you want to extract is stored in data.loc instead of loc.

Answer (score 1):

**There are a few things you need to modify to make it works**

First, remove the extra brackets in your component props:

```
<MapWrapper data={json} loc={foo}/>
```

Second, Because they are props so you will then need to access them inside brackets:

```
const MapWrapper = ({data, loc}) => {
...
```

For that empty data in the initial load, I'd suggest you check for an empty array before making any request.

```
if (foo.length > 0) {
   // Do fetch
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have one question though, how to go about assigning the value of the `geocodeByAddress` function?

Comment: @B.Cratty Sorry, I don't really get it. You might need to create another question for that?

Comment: It's a function that makes a request so it is awaiting promise. In other words it's an async function. So i guess how do I get the value of an async function within a child component?

Comment: You can either wrap it inside an async function or get the value in the next render.

Comment: how would I go about that? I created an async function but confused on where to go from there

Comment: any chance you could take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71226398/async-function-in-reactjs/71226798?noredirect=1#comment125903896_71226798?